# RectangleShape Usercontrol Pass Shape_Click Event to Usercontrol_Click in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, click, shapes, onmouseclick

In VB.Net I am putting a RectangleShape on a user control. When I click on the shape as a usercontrol I want the usercontrol Click Event to Activate. I have tried various things but to no avail. It will fire a button Click but not the Usercontrol Click Event. I am a VB6 programmer trying to learn the VB.net and it is perplexing. I hope somebody out ther knows how to do this many thanks in advance.

I tried many things but not worked. It seems I should be able to send the Shape Click event to the usercontrol Click event but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Throughout the .NET framework, an event named `ExampleEvent` has a corresponding `OnExampleEvent` method that raises it. If you want to raise a user control's `Click` event, you call its `OnClick` method. If you want to raise the container event when the child event is raised, handle the child event and call the `OnClick` method in the event handler, e.g.

```vb
Private Sub ChildControl_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChildControl.Click
    OnClick(EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

To learn more about how events work internally, you might like to read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html).

Comment: I had tried this before but I tried it again and it works on the usercontrol itself but does not work when you click on the RectangleShape placed on the usercontrol. I am going to read "Learn more about"

Comment: Ok, it seems I have the click event working but when I want to use OnMousedown(EventArgs.Empty) or OnMousedown(MouseEventArgs.Empty) it just gives me an error. I need the mousedown so I can have a popupmenu on right mouse click. I am perplexed to say the least

Comment: @MarkAllanWright, you asked about the Click event and you have confirmed that that question has been answered, so accept the answer and move on. If you now have a different question, post a new question properly, with only the information relevant to the new question. You don't ask new questions in comments on answers.

Comment: jmcilhinney What are you talking about? The issue is about Event Handlers. I gave the OnClick as an example. Being able to call the events, OnClick, OnMousedown, OnMouseUp etc. is the issue and it is NOT resolved. The OnClick Event now works but nothing else does and I don't need attitude I need a solution.

Comment: @MarkAllanWright, go back and read your question and tell me what part hasn't been addressed. You did NOT ask about event handlers in general. You asked about the Click event specifically. It's not for us to provide an answer to the question in your head. We answer the question you actually wrote. If the question you want answered is not the one you wrote, edit what you wrote to ask the question you actually want answered. You need to be specific.

Comment: @MarkAllanWright, apart from that, you've already got all the information you need because the blog link I provided demonstrates and explains how to raise events that pass something other than a basic EventArgs.